# System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Char] in C#

Tags: c#, oop

I tried to get a value from Excel loaded for Timeout.

I used:

```
var Timeout = rows[i]["Timeout"].ToString().ToList();
```

But I'm getting `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Char]` instead of the values

Comment: What were you expecting to get from turning a string into a list?

Comment: some of the pre-defined values must be printed in the list

Answer (score 0):

You are getting

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Char]

as a result because you are calling `ToList()` on a `string`. Calling `ToList()` on a string will give you each character of the string in form of a `List<char>`.

My guess is that you are calling this line

```cs
var Timeout = rows[i]["Timeout"].ToString().ToList();
```

inside of a for-loop. In this case I think what you want is getting the *Timeout* column for reach row. This can be achieved in the following way:

```cs
var timeouts = new List<string>();
for(var i = 0; i < rowCount;i++)
{
   timeouts.Add(rows[i]["Timeout"].ToString());
}
```

Now `timeouts` will contain the values for the *Timeout* column for each row.

Comment: If this is not what you want to achieve, you have to give us some more context.